# How to use AWS CLI to get all access keys only by how old they are

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I want to create a script, and perhaps run it in a cron job every 24 hours, which will list all access keys older than 60 days.

I also want to shove the keys older than 60 days into an array so I can iterate over it and perform other options.

I'm looking at [Managing access keys for IAM users - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html) and it has a `aws iam get-access-key-last-used` command but that's not what I want.  But it's the closet thing I can find.

What I want to get the key where current date - `creation date > 60 days`.

I'm imagining my script would look something like this:

```
# some of this is pseudocode just to 
# communicate what I'm envisioning.
# I don't actually know what to put
# here yet; need assistance.

myCommand = "aws cli get key where age > 60"
staleKeys=( $( $myCommand) )

for key in "${staleKeys[@]}"
do
   # log "${key}"
   # run another aws cli command with ${key} as a value
done
```

Is this possible from the AWS CLI?

Comment: When you list access keys, each key in the response includes the CreateDate. You can infer the age.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend [Getting credential reports for your AWS account - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_getting-report.html). This is an automated process that can generate a CSV file listing lots of information about credentials, including:

- The date and time when the user's access key was created or last changed
- The date and time when the user's access key was most recently used to sign an AWS API request

The report can be obtained by calling `generate-credential-report`, waiting a bit, then calling `get-credential-report`. The response needs to be base64 decoded. The result looks like this:

```
user,arn,user_creation_time,password_enabled,password_last_used,password_last_changed,password_next_rotation,mfa_active,access_key_1_active,access_key_1_last_rotated,access_key_1_last_used_date,access_key_1_last_used_region,access_key_1_last_used_service,access_key_2_active,access_key_2_last_rotated,access_key_2_last_used_date,access_key_2_last_used_region,access_key_2_last_used_service,cert_1_active,cert_1_last_rotated,cert_2_active,cert_2_last_rotated
user1,arn:aws:iam::111111111111:user/user1,2019-04-08T05:57:22+00:00,true,2020-05-20T10:55:03+00:00,2019-04-18T00:43:43+00:00,N/A,false,true,2019-04-08T05:57:24+00:00,2019-12-05T21:23:00+00:00,us-west-2,iot,true,2019-11-18T09:38:54+00:00,N/A,N/A,N/A,false,N/A,false,N/A
```

If you decide to generate the information yourself, please note that `list_access_keys()` only returns information about **a single user**. Therefore, you would need to iterate through all users, and call `list_access_keys()` for each user to obtain the `CreationDate` of the keys.

For an example of usage, see: [How to scan your AWS account for old access keys using python - DEV Community](https://dev.to/razcodes/how-to-scan-your-aws-account-for-old-access-keys-using-python-21kk)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm trying to automate something.  So getting pulling down a static CSV means I need to write extra stuff to parse the sheet.  Isn't there a way to do this from the CLI?

Comment: I would recommend using a scripting language like Python to request the file and parse the CSV. Using shell script is typically harder than using a "real" language. However, you could use the AWS CLI to request the report and shell tools like `cut` to process the CSV file.

Comment: > Using shell script is typically harder than using a "real" language.  How about letting me making that determination.  My question was is this possible from the CLI.  Not improve my design for me.  If I have to, I'll use python to pull the data but I was hoping to not go down that road.  Thanks again.

Comment: The CLI can be used to request the report and download the report. You'll need to do the rest yourself, including base64 decoding and parsing the CSV. The documentation link in my answer includes instructions about how to do it from the AWS CLI.

Answer (score 4):

I use the following Python boto3 script, not AWS CLI.

Hope this help those who wanna use boto3:

```py
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timezone

def utc_to_local(utc_dt):
    return utc_dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).astimezone(tz=None)

def diff_dates(date1, date2):
    return abs(date2 - date1).days

resource = boto3.resource('iam')
client = boto3.client("iam")

KEY = 'LastUsedDate'

for user in resource.users.all():
    Metadata = client.list_access_keys(UserName=user.user_name)
    if Metadata['AccessKeyMetadata']:
        for key in user.access_keys.all():
            
            AccessId = key.access_key_id
            Status = key.status
            CreatedDate = key.create_date

            numOfDays = diff_dates(utc_to_local(datetime.utcnow()), utc_to_local(CreatedDate))
            LastUsed = client.get_access_key_last_used(AccessKeyId=AccessId)

            if (Status == "Active"):
                if KEY in LastUsed['AccessKeyLastUsed']:
                    print("User:", user.user_name,  "Key:", AccessId, "Last Used:", LastUsed['AccessKeyLastUsed'][KEY], "Age of Key:", numOfDays, "Days")
                else:
                    print("User:", user.user_name , "Key:",  AccessId, "Key is Active but NEVER USED")
            else:
                print("User:", user.user_name , "Key:",  AccessId, "Keys is InActive")
    else:
        print("User:", user.user_name , "No KEYS for this USER")
```